# Compute gradient of this expression more quickly

Tags: vector-analysis

I want to compute
$$\vec{n}\cdot \nabla^\prime G(\,\vec{r},\,\vec{r}^\prime)$$
with
$$G(\,\vec{r},\,\vec{r}^\prime) = \frac{1}{|\,\vec{r}-\vec{r}^\prime|}-\frac{\frac{R}{r^\prime}}{|\,\vec{r}-\left(\frac{R}{r^\prime}\right)^2\,\vec{r}^\prime|},\quad 0<R\in\mathbb{R},\quad r^\prime = |\,\vec{r}^\prime|.$$

Now, since $\vec{\,n}$ is the outer normal of a sphere, I want to compute this in spherical coordinates. However, writing down nabla in spherical coordinates and applying it to the above expression results in a quite tedious task.
Is there any other, quicker way of doing this?

Comment: You don't have any angular terms so the angular parts of the gradient are zero. Besides, putting this in Cartesian components will be extremely nasty I think.

Comment: Note that I have dependencies that include vectors, i.e. $\vec{r}^\prime = \left(r^\prime\sin\theta^\prime\cos\phi^\prime,\,r^\prime\sin\theta^\prime\sin \phi^\prime ,\,r^\prime\cos\theta^\prime\right)^T$. This results in a dependence in all three variables.

Comment: Oh damn I see. It is still best to use sphereical I would say.

Answer (score 0):

This is how far I get:
We have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'}
\left[
x_i -
\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 x_i' 
\right] =
-R^2
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'}
\left[
\left(\sum_i x_i'^2\right)^{-1}x_i'
\right] =
-R^2\left(
-2\frac{x_i'^2}{|r'|^4} +\frac{1}{|r'|^2}
\right) =
\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2\left(
2\frac{x_i'^2}{|r'|^2} - 1
\right)
\quad (1)
$$

and so
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'}
\left|r -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 r'\right| =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'}
\sqrt{\sum_i \left(x_i -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 x_i'\right)^2} = \\
\frac{\left(x_i -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 x_i'\right)
\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2\left(
2\frac{x_i'^2}{|r'|^2} - 1
\right)
}
{\left|r -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 r'\right|}
\quad (2)
$$

and thus
$$
\left[\nabla' G(r, r')\right]_i = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'} G(r, r') = \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'} \frac{1}{|r -r'|} -
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'} 
\frac{\frac{R}{|r'|}}{\left|r -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 r'\right|} = \\
\frac{x_i - x_i'}{|r -r'|^3} -
\frac{-R\frac{x_i'}{|r'|^3} \left|r -(\frac{R}{|r'|})^2 r'\right|
-\frac{R}{|r'|}
\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2\left(
2\frac{x_i'^2}{|r'|^2} - 1
\right)
}{\left|r -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 r'\right|^2} = \\
\frac{x_i - x_i'}{|r -r'|^3} +
\frac{\frac{R}{|r'|}\frac{x_i'}{|r'|^2}}{\left|r -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 r'\right|} -
\frac{
\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^3\left(
2\frac{x_i'^2}{|r'|^2} - 1
\right)
}{\left|r -\left(\frac{R}{|r'|}\right)^2 r'\right|^2}
\quad (3)
$$
where I probably made errors. :-)

The rest depends on how your $n$ is defined, is it $n = r/|r|$ or $n = r'/|r'|$?